# Scroll a particular div tag

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
#points{
  width:25%;
  background:#2a2a2a; 
  height:20px; 
  color:white; 
  z-index:2;
  position:absolute;
}
#areas{
  position:absolute;
  color:white; 
  border-right:2px solid black; 
  height:120%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width:100%">
  <div class="scale" style="width:100%; position:relative;">
    <div id="points" style="left:0; ">0</div>
    <div id="points" style="left:25%;">25</div>
    <div id="points" style="left:50%;">50</div>
    <div id="points" style=" left:75%;">75</div>
    <div id="points" style=" left:100%;">100</div>
    <div id="points" style=" left:125%;">125</div>
    <div id="points" style=" left:150%;">150</div>
  </div>

  <div class="area" style="width:100%; background:orange;">
    <div id="areas" style="left:0;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:25%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:50%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:75%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:100%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:125%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:150%;"></div>
    <div id="areas" style="left:175%;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

While scrolling to top and bottom, I would only like to scroll the `area` div; I don't want the `scale` div to hide from the container while scrolling.

I tried using `position: fixed` for the `scale` div, but it didn't fit correctly with the the scroll left, this case only display the `0 25 50 75`, but each scale points are correspond to the area div tag so display the all div tag `0,25,50,.. 150` with these corresponding `areas` div tags

Is there any other way to do it without `positon: fixed`?

Working fiddle with [postion: absolute](https://jsfiddle.net/1agxgwno/). But the `points` divs are hidden from the container.

[position: fixed](https://jsfiddle.net/1agxgwno/1/). Left side div tags are not visible.

Comment: Perhaps you could scroll only the `area` div and not the entire `container`? Set some fixed height to `area` and `overflow: auto` and it should do the trick

Comment: @Dygestor  i want to scroll the entire container.

Comment: Can you perhaps create a JSFiddle, so we can see exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't use duplicate IDs. Just don't. Correct your question. After that, my guess is you want each of the "points" divs to belong to the corresponding "areas" div? Then why don't you put them together, that is each "points" div as a child of the "areas" div.

Comment: @Dygestor I added fiddle in my question

Comment: @MrLister You are correct. But i create the each div tags in javascript forloop that the reason i dont put them together,

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem now ?

Comment: @Seblor I not found a answer, this is my mistake. sorry and see the fiddle. And thank you for your effort for me.  https://jsfiddle.net/qk37kson/1/

Answer (score 10):

Do you want something like that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/qk37kson/ **(Edited : added a little bit of JQuery to make the header move horizontally)**

1) The `id` attribute has to be unique. That's why in JavaScript we have `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`.

From W3Schools :

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_class.asp

> The class attribute specifies one or more classnames for an element.

2) change

```
 <div class="scale" style="width:100%; position:relative;">
```

to

```
 <div id="scale" style="width:100%; position:fixed;">
```

3) then, in your CSS, add this :

```
#scale {
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:2;
}
```

**Edit :**

4) Finally, add some JQuery :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#scale').css('left','-'+$(window).scrollLeft()+'px');
});
```

Comment: Every line corresponding to the `points` in your case  only display the `0 25 50 75`. But i want to display all points. In that case `position:relative` is fit for me but the problem of the position relative was when scroll top to bottom points are hided from the area.?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the header couldn't move at all. I added a little bit of JQuery to make that work.

Comment: I not found a answer, this is my mistake. sorry and see the https://jsfiddle.net/qk37kson/1/. And thank you for your effort for me

Answer (score 1):

You could keep `.container`'s `overflow-y` to hidden and `.area`'s `overflow-y` to scroll. Thereby the container would scroll `.scale` and `.area` along x but not y, but the `.area` will scroll along `y` within itself giving you your effect.